# How do I build real-time recommender system with Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, real-time, recommendation-engine

All i can find until now is some recommender engines that build and deploy everything in memory based on csv files as datasets, so if have about 1 M of data and about 3700 user per day.
Im my case , my company has about 1 M active item , about 4000 active user (avg) per day and about 4.5 M page visit per week (avg).

The idea to build, train and recommand items in the memory seams so bad , so i'm thinking to build a recommander engine but kind of real-time ! how ? that's what i'm looking for, maybe train data and deploy it to an indexer like elasticsearch or something similar to recommand items.

Any seggestion ?

Comment: Spark can still handle data that won't fit in memory, have you seen this [article](https://0x0fff.com/spark-memory-management/)?

Answer (score 1):

Few things I would consider do it.

- Using machine learning to extract features from item, this would possibly be retrained again an again
- Analyse use behaviours on those item, include click stream
- Using A-B test to verify algorithm
- Using Spark Stream